# HELP I have root:"REVERT opcode executed. Message: 2"

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract Contract1 {
    
    uint index;
    address owner;
    uint256[] values;
    
    mapping(uint => address payable) addresses;
    
    constructor() {
       owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function makeAPay() public payable {
        uint tempValue = msg.value/(10**6);
        addresses[index] = payable(msg.sender);
        values[index] = tempValue;
        index++;
    }
    
    
    function getAdr() public view returns(address) {
        if(index == 0){
            return owner;
        }
        return addresses[0];
    }
    
    function getValue() public view returns(uint) {
        if(index == 0){
            return 0;
        }
            return values[0];
    }
    
     function getIndex() public view returns(uint) {
            return index;
    }

    function getOwner() public view returns(address) {
            return owner;
    }
}
```

Why I always get root:"REVERT opcode executed. Message: 2"
When I makeAPay() with any payable value

```
 status false Transaction mined but execution failed
```

when i commit, problem was gone, but i dont get value)

```
        uint tempValue = msg.value/(10**6);
        values[index] = tempValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

As `values` is an array, you can check the value by passing an `uint id` in your `getValue` function and simply return `values[id]`. Also, I don't see the use for the index value with the `values` array. For the function `makeAPay()` you're not pushing the item in the array, hence you're getting 0. Instead of `values[index] = tempValue` it should be `values.push(tempValue)`. That way you're actually occupying the position in the array with the `tempValue`.If you want to check if there are any values in the array you can get all the values in the array by returning `uint[]` instead of simple `uint`.